# Rails: Track click on every link in Ruby on Rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

The current requirement I have is to create a record in a Postgres DB whenever any object in the app is clicked. It is a large project with hundreds of links and pages. If a user clicks on an anchor, or a clickable div, or a button, I want to create a record in the DB.

The code for the call is as follows:

```
AppEvent.record_event(event_type: 'example', url: request.fullpath, user: current_user.name)
```

I am using it to track page transitions now, but how do I track clicking on a div or anchor with that function? Is it possible to do with JS in some capacity?

Comment: Take a look at how [Ahoy](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy) does it [here](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/ahoy.js#L485)

Comment: This has to be done on the client-side. You can create a virtual "page" (an API end-point) on your rails application which records info from request.query or body. Add an event listener for click event to [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) POST information about click to this API end-point. The controller will read the body and create the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, you can use [`Ahoy`](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy) analytics for Rails if you don't want to use this gem then you create this simply defining a method, at first I think your tracking table is `app_events` then your model is `AppEvent` then your models look like this relation

```
#=> user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

  .....
  has_many :app_events
  ....
end

#=> app_event.rb
class AppEvent < ApplicationRecord

  .....
  belongs_to :users
  ....
end
```

your `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :track_event, if: proc { user_signed_in? }


    def track_event
      current_user.app_events.create(event_type: params[:event_type], url: params[:url]) if  params[:event_type].present?
    end
end
```

and your links look like this

```
root_path(event_type: 'home', url: request.fullpath)
about_path(event_type: 'about', url: request.fullpath)
news_path(event_type: 'news', url: request.fullpath)
...
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks.